# Canadian transit visa time constraint

Tags: indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas, vancouver, emergencies

I am an Indian student studying in USA. I am travelling to India from San Francisco on December 27th, 2017 and have a layover in Vancouver. I applied for a transit visa on November 28th. The estimated processing time right now is 19 days (if the application is filled up correctly) but I also have to mail my passport to Los Angeles, which may take more time itself.

Is there any way I could convey my time constraint to the authorities so that they could help me and give me a speedy decision? Can I personally go to Los Angeles and get my passport stamped in a day or so?

Comment: It is bizarre to fly **via Canada** from SF to Mumbai.  Just have your ticket changed to a normal flight.  This will cost far less than the complications mentioned.

Comment: The literal answers to your questions:  "Is there anyway I could convey my time constraint to the authorities so that they could help me and give me a speedy decision"  **No**  "Can I personally go to Los Angeles and get my Passport stamped in a day or so?" **No**

Answer (score 2):

Sending a passport will take less then a day. Good applications will be processed quicker than a too much verbose or an incomplete application.  Sometime with a fee, there is fast track (usually for emergencies, which is really not your case: for emergency you will flight the most direct way, without layover).

But why do you think you deserve special procedures, over people who applied in time?  These requests are not well seen by authorities.  BTW, it is your job to apply in time.